# Sampling distribution of sample means question (Newbold)

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, mean

6.3 from Newbold (8th ed.):

> A population contains 6 million 0s and 4 million 1s. What is the approximate sampling distribution of the sample mean in each of the following cases?
>
> - The sample size is n = 5
> - The sample size is n = 100
>
> Note: There is a hard way and an easy way to answer this question. We recommend the latter.

So this is binomial distribution with  P=0.4 and n = 5 / n=100. In the case of n = 5 the possible values of the sample mean are 0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8, and 1. But I can't figure out how to get the probabilities. In the case of n = 5 I guess I could plug the values of X-bar into the binomial formula (I'm guessing this is what the authors meant by the "hard way"?), but what about when n = 100? What is the "easy" way?

Comment: Does the book define 'approximate sampling distribution' in some way? You could think of approximate sampling distribution as equivalent to the asymptotic distribution, and just invoke the CLT even, especially for n=100.

Comment: @doubled, no, this is at the very beginning of the first chapter about sampling/inferential statistics, CLT has not even been mentioned, nor asymptotic distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really unclear what the book is asking, since without context, 'approximate sampling distribution' is quite unclear, especially if the book hasn't defined it yet!

My best guess is that the approximation maybe comes from assuming that you draw iid individuals from the population, because 5 and 100 are really small compared to 10 million. So you draw binomial with $P = .4,n = n$ as you noted, though this is approximate because of the slightly non-iidness of the data. So you have $X \sim B(P,n)$, and want to know the distribution of $\hat{X_n} = \frac{X}{n}$. So you want to know

$$P( \hat{X_n} = x | P=P, n = n) = P(X = xn| P=p, n= n)$$

but you know the distribution of $P(X = x|P=P,n=n)$ as it's binomial, so you're done (recall that  $P(X = x|P=P,n=n) = {n \choose x}P^x(1-P)^{n-x}$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @doubled. I understand what you are saying but I still don't understand how I would get the actual distribution. The book in a previous example says that e.g. if you flip a coin twice, the sampling distribution for the sample means is:  0:0.25, 1:0.5, 2:0.25. So, in the above question for n = 5, I expect something like 0:something, 0.2: something, 0.3: something, etc. I suppose this is what I get if I use the binomial formula for all 5 values. But how do I go about this when n = 100?

Comment: I think you're done with my answer. That function, perhaps with plugging in n = 100 and for P, is the distribution. Similarly, if you were asked for the distribution of Binom(100000,.25), you would not hand over thousands of pages of evaluating the probability of any given value in 1-100000, but rather say that the distribution is $P(X=x) = {n \choose x}P^x(1-P)^{n-x}$, and perhaps actually plug in n=100000, and P = .25. The exact same idea applies here.

Comment: Ah, ok, I get the point. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think "the hard way" for $n=5$ could be taking account of the finite population size and using a hypergeometric distribution instead of a binomial.  "The easy way" for n=100 might even be Normal

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasLumley - I never thought of hypergeometric, and it _is_ in the book, in the previous chapters.